# numpy.where on 2d or 3d matrix

Tags: python, numpy

[image: background image]

[image: target]

I want to get the index where the target is located in background image using numpy. the background color of each image is actually varible
so except for the color of the sqaure, other colors (in this case, black painted) including the inside of the square will vary.
i have no idea how to approach this at all as im not familiar with numpy.

```
import numpy as np

#changing to grayscale to have 2d array 
output = cv2.imread('backgroundimage.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
output1 = cv2.imread('target.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

i tried to change the images to 2d array because i thought it might be easier to approach.

```
a = np.where(output==output1)
```

apparently this doesnt work for 2d or 3d.
my desired output will be something like this

```
desired output = (108, 23) (x and y coordination of where its found)
```

so how would i able to do what i want?

Comment: `cv.matchtemplate` doesn't do `a = np.where(output==output1)`, there's a bunch of extra maths in there. `so what do i need to do?` use `cv.matchtemplate` or learn its algorithms ? anyway it depends on what you are comparing, but an `==` on floats is never a good idea anyway.

Comment: @AhmedAEK as i mentioned i want to use numpy instead of matchtemplate. and im asking because im having a hard time understand its algorithms...

Comment: small hint, `cv2.matchtemplate` doesn't have `np.where` in it ... so whoever is seeing this question about `np.where` isn't going to answer you, opencv is also open-source so you can read its sourcecode yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a sliding window approach, and make sure that all pixels are equal for each window you compare with the target. You can do that using [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) and [`all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html). You can mask out any values inside the target that you do not want to match by setting them to True:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

output = cv2.imread('backgroundimage.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
output1 = cv2.imread('target.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Apply sliding window view
windows = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(output, output1.shape)

# Only check the 1 pixel border by making a mask
mask = np.full_like(output1, False)
mask[1:-1, 1:-1] = True

# Apply mask and check match everywhere
masked = (windows == output1) | mask
matches = masked.all(axis=(2, 3))

locations = np.where(matches)
```

locations:

```
(array([24], dtype=int64), array([108], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: hello sir! your code works perfectly and i appreciate it but the code takes about 0.2 secs and i need at least 10x faster than this. so do you know if theres a way to speed it up or other way for it?

Comment: Hmm, currently we have a mask that sets all the values we do not care about to True, which results in more comparisons than needed. Instead you could omit the mask part and only check the borders of the array (windows == output1), but that makes the code less clean imo :). I'm not sure what the speed difference would be.

Comment: Searching for a subsection of the target, eg. The 4x4 top left pixels, may speed things up. Then check which of any matches also finds the whole target.  I'm not sure what speed improvement you would get or what the optimal size and shape would be.